# Set filter and publish with Python - Is this possible?

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to set filters then publish workbook with tableau server client in Python ?

Basically I want to update what the end user will be shown by default when they get to the view. I am talking about [these filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jfX0.png).

So I would need my script to access the workbook and select another item on the drop down list of the filters, then publish the workbook.

I have run through the API doc but didn't succeed in finding a way to do it.

In my case, I would like yesterday's date to be shown by default : but I still want people to be able to choose other dates if they want to.

Comment: Is your script publishing multiple copies of the workbook, each copy having different values for the filters?

Comment: Only one copy, cannot directly get the formula done in Tableau because I would then need to use parameters, which cannot have multiple values

Comment: Why not just set the filters in Desktop, save it, then publish it? Whatever filter values you have saved in Desktop will become the default values that people see.

Comment: That's what I do at the moment, but it takes some times and I have to update it everyday. Was hoping for a way to automate it to save some time every day.

Comment: Why do you the filter values have to change every day? Maybe there's a way we can help you avoid needing to do that. Please edit your question with what the filter values are that are changing.

Comment: The dashboards are used by pretty much all my company and I want them to display yesterday's date by default while still letting them choose other dates at their will (ie week 12 wednesday). I've updated my question